# Delaying a function in python and kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Me and my friends are doing a project for college, but we got stuck with a problem, we have created a memory game that uses kivy as a graphic interface. The issue is that we can't see the second card when the button is pressed, we've tried using sleep, clock and even while as a cont and now we don't know what do, could someone help us how to get this code fixed?

(def Virar_carta(self,n),line 150)

PYTHON

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from time import sleep



class Tela(BoxLayout):
  imagem_fundo = StringProperty('Carta-verso-Oficial.png')  
  imagem1 = StringProperty('carta1.png')
  imagem2 = StringProperty('carta2.png')
  imagem3 = StringProperty('carta3.png')
  imagem4 = StringProperty('carta4.png')
  imagem5 = StringProperty('carta5.png')
  imagem6 = StringProperty('carta6.png')
  imagem7 = StringProperty('Carta7.png')
  imagem8 = StringProperty('Carta8.png')
  imagem9 = StringProperty('Carta9.png')
  imagem10 = StringProperty('carta10.png')

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    BoxLayout.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    self.quantidade_jogadores = 1
    self.turno = 0
    self.cartas_clicadas = []
    self.numero_de_cartas = 12
    self.ListaCartas_imagens_origem = [
      self.imagem1, self.imagem2, self.imagem3, self.imagem4, self.imagem5,
      self.imagem6, self.imagem7, self.imagem8, self.imagem9, self.imagem10
    ]
    self.ListaCartas_imagens = []
    self.ListaCartas_numero = [self.ids.carta1, self.ids.carta2, self.ids.carta3, self.ids.carta4,
      self.ids.carta5, self.ids.carta6, self.ids.carta7, self.ids.carta8,
      self.ids.carta9, self.ids.carta10, self.ids.carta11, self.ids.carta12,
      self.ids.carta13, self.ids.carta14, self.ids.carta15, self.ids.carta16,
      self.ids.carta17, self.ids.carta18, self.ids.carta19, self.ids.carta20]
    self.pontuacoes = [0]
    self.som_acabou = SoundLoader.load('GameOver.wav') 
    self.opcoes=[]
    self.ordem_de_imagens=[]
    self.vencedor=[]
    
    
  def Pega_info(self, id, text):
    if id == 'jogadores':
      if text == '1':
        self.quantidade_jogadores = 1
        self.pontuacoes=[0]
      elif text == '2':
        self.quantidade_jogadores = 2
        self.pontuacoes=[0,0]
      elif text == '3':
        self.quantidade_jogadores = 3
        self.pontuacoes=[0,0,0]
      else:
        self.quantidade_jogadores = 4
        self.pontuacoes=[0,0,0,0]
    else:  
      if text == '12':
        self.numero_de_cartas = 12
      elif text == '16': 
        self.numero_de_cartas = 16
      else:
        self.numero_de_cartas = 20

  def Embaralhar(self):

    n = int(self.numero_de_cartas / 2)
    for i in range(0, n):
      self.opcoes.append(i)
      self.opcoes.append(i)
    self.ordem_de_imagens = random.sample(self.opcoes, self.numero_de_cartas)
    for j in self.ordem_de_imagens:
      self.ListaCartas_imagens.append(self.ListaCartas_imagens_origem[j])
    print(self.ListaCartas_imagens) #[imagem1,imagem2,imagem1,imagem3,imagem2,imagem3]

  def Montar_grid(self):   
    #comment Bia: nesse vai depender do numero escolhido de cartas , vamos desativar os botões q não precisarem/ + opacidade zero e colocar as imagens nas cartas
    if self.numero_de_cartas == 12:
      for indice in range(self.numero_de_cartas):  #faz com que o indice assuma um dos ids das cartas
        id_botao = self.ListaCartas_numero[indice]  #cria uma variavel que assume o nome do id do botão
        id_botao.disabled = not id_botao.disabled  #muda o disabled de False para True
        id_botao.opacity = 1  #Muda a opacidade de 0 para 1

    elif self.numero_de_cartas == 16:
      for indice in range(self.numero_de_cartas):
        id_botao = self.ListaCartas_numero[indice]
        id_botao.disabled = not id_botao.disabled
        id_botao.opacity = 1

    else:
      for indice in range(self.numero_de_cartas):
        id_botao = self.ListaCartas_numero[indice]
        id_botao.disabled = not id_botao.disabled
        id_botao.opacity = 1
    self.ids.novojogo.disabled = not self.ids.novojogo.disabled  #desablita o botão novo jogo
    self.ids.pecas.disabled = not self.ids.pecas.disabled  #desabilita o spinner para escolha do numero de jogadores
    self.ids.jogadores.disabled = not self.ids.jogadores.disabled
    self.ids.dadosjogo.opacity = 1
    #repetir o mesmo passo para os outros jogadores
    self.Embaralhar()
    for i in range(len(self.ListaCartas_imagens)):
      self.ListaCartas_numero[i].background_disabled_normal=self.ListaCartas_imagens[i]
      
  def Fim(self):
    self.som_acabou.play() 
    pontuacao_vencedor=self.pontuacoes[0]
    vencedores=[]
    venc=0
    for i in range(len(self.pontuacoes)):  #(1,2,3,3)
      if self.pontuacoes[i]>pontuacao_vencedor:
        venc=i+1  #venc=3
        pontuacao_vencedor=self.pontuacoes[i]  #pontuacao_vencedor=3
    if venc!=0:
      vencedores.append(venc)  #vencedores=[3]
    for j in range(len(self.pontuacoes)):  #(1,2,3,3)
      if pontuacao_vencedor==self.pontuacoes[j] and venc!=j+1: #if 3==self.pontuacoes[j] and 3!=j+1
        vencedores.append(j+1) #vencedores=[3,4]
    for k in range(len(vencedores)):
      self.vencedor.append(f'{vencedores[k]}') #vencedor=['3','4']
    self.ids.fim.opacity=1
    print(vencedores)
    self.ids.vencs.text=(', '.join(self.vencedor))

    #Comentario Bia:desativa botões, mostra o ganhador, toca som de final, talvez zere tudo pro novo jogo, dps de passar oq precisar
  def Acabar(self):
    #Comentário Bia: planejamento de funcionamento: if pontuação já for maxima , acaba jogo (caso 1 jogador), se mais jogadores, acaba se a soma das pontuações for igual ao número de cartas/2 -> quer dizer que a cada par 1 ponto
    soma=0
    if self.quantidade_jogadores == 1:
      if self.pontuacoes[0] == self.numero_de_cartas / 2:
        self.Fim()
    else:
      for i in range(len(self.pontuacoes)):
        soma += self.pontuacoes[i]
      if soma == self.numero_de_cartas / 2:
        self.Fim()

  def Troca_turno(self):
    self.turno+=1
    if self.turno==(self.quantidade_jogadores):
      self.turno=0
    jog=self.turno+1
    self.ids.vezjogador.text=(f'{jog}')
    self.ids.pontosjogador.text=(f'{self.pontuacoes[self.turno]}')
    self.Acabar()
#################################HERE
  def Virar_carta(self,n):#n: numero botão 
    certo = False
    indice_carta=int(n)
    carta=self.ListaCartas_numero[indice_carta]
    carta.disabled=True
    self.cartas_clicadas.append(carta) 
    if len(self.cartas_clicadas) == 2:
      certo = self.Comparar_cartas()  #vai pedir pra comparar
      if certo == True:
        self.Sumir_par() 
        self.pontuacoes[self.turno] += 1
        #entra na lista de pontuações, no index turno (primeiro é zero) e aumenta 1 caso esteja certo
        self.cartas_clicadas = []
      else:
        self.Normal_carta() 
        self.cartas_clicadas = []
      if self.quantidade_jogadores != 1:
        self.Troca_turno()
      #mudei o nome da função, ela vai pegar e aumentar o numero certinho, e quando já estiver em sei lá 3 (ex: são 4 jogadores e self.turno começa em 0) ele volta pra 0


  def Normal_carta(self):
    self.cartas_clicadas[0].background_normal = 'Carta-verso-Oficial.png'
    self.cartas_clicadas[1].background_normal = 'Carta-verso-Oficial.png'
    self.cartas_clicadas[0].disabled = False
    self.cartas_clicadas[1].disabled = False

  def Comparar_cartas(self):  #passar id da carta , vão ser carta'n' o 'n' vai ser o número #mudar comparação entre imagens
    if self.cartas_clicadas[0].background_disabled_normal==self.cartas_clicadas[1].background_disabled_normal:
      return True
    else:
      return False


  def Sumir_par(self):
    self.cartas_clicadas[0].opacity = 0
    self.cartas_clicadas[0].disabled = True
    self.cartas_clicadas[1].opacity = 0
    self.cartas_clicadas[1].disabled = True


  def sair(self):
    App.get_running_app().stop()


class JogoApp(App):

  def build(self):
    Window.size = (600, 600)
    self.title = 'Jogo da Memória'
    return Tela()


JogoApp().run()
```

KIVY

```
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<Tela>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:(1,0.25)
        orientation:"horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(0.4,1)
            orientation:"vertical"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: get_color_from_hex('#F4A460')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'
                Label:
                    text:'Jogadores:'
                    font_size:20
                    color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                Spinner:          
                    id:jogadores
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: None #permite q eu possa mexer na altura
                    height:30
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    values: ('1','2','3','4')
                    text:'-'
                    on_text:root.Pega_info('jogadores',jogadores.text)
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'
                Label:
                    text:'Peças:'
                    font_size: 20
                    color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                Spinner:
                    id:pecas
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height:30
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,'center_y':0.5}
                    values: ('12','16','20')
                    text: '-'
                    on_text:root.Pega_info('pecas',pecas.text)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: get_color_from_hex('#FFDAB9')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text:'Jogo da memória'
                font_size:20
                color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
            Label:
                text:'Selecione o número de jogadores e de cartas, \n           clique "Novo Jogo" para iniciar.'
                color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
            Label:
                text:'Clique nas cartas e tente fazer os pares!'
                color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: get_color_from_hex('#FFDAB9')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint:(0.4,1)
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint:(1,0.5)
                orientation:'vertical'
                id: dadosjogo
                opacity: 0
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    Label:
                        text:'Vez do jogador:'
                        color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                    Label:
                        size_hint:(0.5,1)
                        id: vezjogador
                        text:'1'
                        color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    Label:
                        text:'Pontuação:'
                        color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                    Label:
                        size_hint:(0.5,1)
                        id: pontosjogador
                        text: '0'
                        color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    opacity:0
                    id: fim
                    Label:
                        text: 'Parabéns!! Vencedor(es):'
                        color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        Label:
                            text: 'Jogador(es)'
                            color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')
                        Label:
                            id:vencs
                            text: '-'
                            color: get_color_from_hex('#0d0d0b')

            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint:(1,0.3)
                Button:
                    id: novojogo
                    size_hint:(1,0.5)
                    text:"Novo Jogo"
                    font_size:30
                    background_color: get_color_from_hex('#F4A460')
                    on_press: root.Montar_grid()
                Button:
                    size_hint:(1,0.5)
                    text:"Sair"
                    font_size:30
                    background_color: get_color_from_hex('#F4A460')
                    on_press: root.sair()  
        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: get_color_from_hex('#F4A460')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            cols:4
            rows:5
            Button:
                id:carta1
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('0') 
            Button:
                id:carta2
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('1') 
            Button:
                id:carta3
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('2') 
            Button:
                id:carta4
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('3') 
            Button:
                id:carta5
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('4') 
            Button:
                id:carta6
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('5') 
            Button:
                id:carta7
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('6') 
            Button:
                id:carta8
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('7') 
            Button:
                id:carta9
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('8') 
            Button:
                id:carta10
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('9') 
            Button:
                id:carta11
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('10') 
            Button:
                id:carta12
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('11') 
            Button:
                id:carta13
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('12') 
            Button:
                id:carta14
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('13') 
            Button:
                id:carta15
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('14') 
            Button:
                id:carta16
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('15') 
            Button:
                id:carta17
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('16') 
            Button:
                id:carta18
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('17') 
            Button:
                id:carta19
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('18') 
            Button:
                id:carta20
                opacity:0
                disabled:True
                background_normal:"Carta-verso-Oficial.png"
                on_press: root.Virar_carta('19')
```

We tried time.sleep(), clock(), while as a count. We want the second card, when clicked, to show the image before calling the comparison functions etc.

Comment: Have you tried `Clock.schedule_once()`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, and it's the same as sleep(). It seems that the image is changing only at the end of the function, even if the command is made before the one that calls the comparison function.